# Using webcam or device camera to capture photo

Tags: php, javascript, flash, html

Hello there lately I've been reading a lot about `getusermedia()` and as far as I know this API is not reliable for use in a final app. I want to build a webpage that allows the user capture a photo or upload one.

So I need alternatives. What's the *best* multi-platform (pc/mac, ipad, iphone, androids, etc) way to capture a photo from a webcam or device camera? Java? Flash? Other?

Any articles or tutorials are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getUserMedia` API is only currently [supported in Chrome and Opera](http://caniuse.com/#search=getusermedia). As such, the best multi-platform approach will almost certainly need to involve Flash as a fallback. Because iOS  supports neither Flash nor the `getUserMedia` API (currently), you may need to consider developing a native app to support this platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this libs to integrate to your application:

http://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/

Comment: Does this library support android and iOS devices?

Comment: if you want to target mobile devices. you need to use some of the framework. such as phonegap http://phonegap.com/

Comment: It relies on Flash so it won't work on iOS.